# Hyperlink Addresses on Access Database to Google Earth

Tags: vba, ms-access, google-earth

I'm developing an Access Database and want to create a direct hyperlink on the forms to the customers address.  The hyperlink would open the Google Earth Pro application and use the address to locate the unit.

I have tried a hyperlink but don't see any literature on how you can integrate with Google Earth Pro.

Comment: Alternative approach is Microsoft Web Browser control. I just tested it and it works. https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/comp.databases.ms-access/PgurnoTFIR4

Comment: AFAIK, passing data to GoogleEarth requires building a KML file and opening the KML. App set as default for that file type will open and load data.

Comment: If Google Maps would work, then you can do this quite easily by creating a link that looks like:
https://www.google.com/maps/search/<address>
for example: 
https://www.google.com/maps/search/20+W+34th+St,+New+York,+NY+10001
(make sure to replace spaces in the address with "+" symbols.